# Update fields with user position using a service

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to update some fields when I receive a geoposition for a give user.

Until know I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/10/

Firstly, I get a `Error: Unknown provider: positionProvider <- position` (only on jsfiddle). I do not get this error on my real site.

The problem is that when I get the position I update the `position` object in the service but it does not update in the HTML view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/17/)

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', []);
var services = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
services.factory('position', ['$http', function ($http) { ...
```

should be

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', []);
test.factory('position', ['$http', function ($http) { ...
```

You should update the controller code as this, to use a callback function and $apply to apply the value set to the scope.

```
position.getPosition(function (p) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.position.latitude = p.coords.latitude;
        $scope.position.longitude = p.coords.longitude;
        $scope.position.accuracy = p.coords.accuracy;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the first fix. Do you know why if you accept to provide your geolocation `N/A` is not update to a real value?

Comment: I think the problem is because the factory returns asynchronously, thus the position.latitude = "N/A" and then updates accordingly. Can you provide a fixed jsfiddle?

Comment: @salamis. Done. please check.