# AngularJS bind click of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a directive (or in another way ?), I'm looking for binding multiple elements for launching the same actions.

My directive now :

```
angular.module('myApp.directivePlayer', [])
    .directive('btnOne', ['version', function(version) {

        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function($scope, btnOne, attrs) {
                btnOne.bind('click', function() {

                    // My stuff

                });
            }
        }  
    }
]);
```

I want to do "my stuff" on click of `btnOne` and `btnTwo`. With jQuery and Css selectors, something like `$('.btnOne, .btnTwo').awesomeEffect();`. How to do this with AngularJS without duplicate "my stuff" ?

Comment: Couldn't you place your stuff in a service and inject that service into your module []?

Comment: Ok, I'll try and how to put two directives (stupid question...!) ? When I create more than one, only the last is fired.

Comment: @Scofred that's the closure issue

Comment: @sza thanks, I solved this issue. How can I call a service from my directive. Do you have a code example ?

Comment: Hi, Take a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/a/17911704/304319